# Changing a global variable with setInterval

Tags: javascript

How can I change the global variable `a` every second using `setInterval`?

Tried this, but it not works as it will reset `a`'s value when leaving `setInterval`.

```
var a=1;
var timerId = setInterval(function(){ 
     a++; 
     alert(a);
     if (a == 5) clearInterval(timerId);
}, 1000);
document.write(a);
```

Eventually, is there any better way to do it, other than setInterval?

Comment: That's working just fine, it's just that the `setInterval` is **asynchronous**, so the document.write happens even before the interval starts

Comment: As adeneo said. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/w4mryc91/

Comment: @adeneo you seems to be right: https://jsfiddle.net/yscvf8t1/